# Splitting file by date

Tags: date, csv, split

I have a 2 GB CSV file that has a few columns and several millions of rows (including a date column formatted as 2010-12-15). I am looking to split this CSV into smaller CSVs that are arranged in folders by the date (for example all entries for December 15, 2010 are located inside a folder named 20101215).

I am fairly new to this stuff but am aware of split command. Can you guys point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how regular and clean your data is, something like this may suffice:

```
for i in `cut -d, -f 2  <csv | sort -u`; do
   mkdir $i && grep $i csv > $i/csv
done
```

(assuming your data is in the file `csv`, and your date info is in the second column)

What is this doing ? The `cut` filters out the dates in the second column, and they're run through `sort -u` to create a sorted list of unique dates. We then iterate through this (the `for` command) and for each entry we `mkdir` a corresponding directory, and grep results out into a csv file within that directory.

It's not ideal. e.g. we grep through the input file for each date. I'm assuming the data is regular, and that a date string (2012-08-06 for example) doesn't appear elsewhere in your data (or has characters that would screw up the above script e.g. spaces and/or `/`).

I don't think the `split` command will help you here. It's more useful for splitting files into regular chunks (by size or by number of lines).